# Get average value per day/hour without Group By

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In a single table, say I have a log of mileage and timestamps. I want to get the average mileage per day and per hour. I can't use an inherent "Group By" clause because of the date format.

Here is some sample data:

```
  Table: tb_mileage
  ===============================================
  f_mileagetimestamp           f_mileage
  -----------------------------------------------
  2014-08-11 11:13:02.000      50                       
  2014-08-11 16:12:55.000      100      
  2014-08-11 16:55:00.000      30                
  2014-08-12 11:12:50.000      80                       
  2014-08-12 16:12:49.000      100                      
  2014-08-13 08:12:46.000      40                       
  2014-08-13 08:45:31.000      100
```

So, the ideal result set would appear as follows (**PER DAY**) (note, format of date doesn't matter):

```
  Date                 Average
  ------------------------------------------------
  08/11/2014           60
  08/12/2014           90
  08/13/2014           70
```

The ideal result set would appear as follows (**PER HOUR**) (note, format of date doesn't matter):

```
  Date                     Average
  ------------------------------------------------
  08/11/2014 11:00:00      50
  08/11/2014 16:00:00      65
  08/12/2014 11:00:00      80
  08/12/2014 16:00:00      100
  08/13/2014 08:00:00      70
```

Note that the example here is purely theoretical and simplified, and doesn't necessarily reflect the exact criteria necessary for the real-world implementation. This is merely to push my own learning, because all the examples I found to do similar things were hugely complex, making learning difficult.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this for the dates version.

```
select cast(t.f_mileagetimestamp as date) as dt, avg(t.f_mileage) as avg_mileage
from
tb_mileage t
group by cast(t.f_mileagetimestamp as date)
order by cast(t.f_mileagetimestamp as date) asc;
```

For the hours version, you can use this.

```
select t2.dt, avg(t2.f_mileage) as avg_mileage
from
(
    select substring(CONVERT(nvarchar(100), t1.f_mileagetimestamp, 121), 1, 13) + ':00' as dt, t1.f_mileage 
    from
    tb_mileage t1
) t2
group by t2.dt
order by t2.dt asc;
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. The "By Day" query makes complete sense.


The "By Hour" one, on the other hand, generates an error that I can't wrap my head around:


Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Comment: I fixed the other one. Isn't it OK too?

Comment: I'm sorry, pressing "ENTER" on the keyboard added the comment rather than wrapping a new line. I wasn't finished with my comment when it submitted.

Comment: Sounds interesting, let me try it.

Comment: It works now, thank you! The query seen above now does indeed work flawlessly. Indeed, the date format is exceptional. I can't say I quite understand yet how the date is concatenated, but I'll work through what you have and play with other examples on my own. Thank you, this is great.

Answer (score 6):

I think this should work for the "day" version:

```
select cast(f_mileagetimestamp as date), avg(f_mileage)
from tb_mileage
group by cast(f_mileagetimestamp as date)
order by cast(f_mileagetimestamp as date);
```

For the hour, I would just use the function:

```
select cast(f_mileagetimestamp as date), datepart(hour, f_mileagetimestamp), avg(f_mileage)
from tb_mileage
group by cast(f_mileagetimestamp as date), datepart(hour, f_mileagetimestamp)
order by cast(f_mileagetimestamp as date), datepart(hour, f_mileagetimestamp);
```

Comment: SQL Server tells me that:
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'date' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @Beems Next time specify that it's SQL Server in your question. And specify the version too.

Comment: I apologize, I tagged as T-SQL thinking that was enough. I forgot people would come here based on just the "SQL" tag.

Comment: @Beems . . . I missed the tsql tag, my fault.  In any case, I just updated the syntax.

Comment: Thanks, that works like a champ. This place never ceases to amaze me with fast answers.